Is PLS appropriate for Predicting Chemical Concentrations from NIR Spectroscopy?
I have a set of NIR spectroscopy data for various beverage samples, each with corresponding concentrations of chemical ingredients (e.g., caffeine). I would like to train a PLS model to predict the concentration of different chemical ingredients from the spectra. However, most of the concentration values are concentrated in a narrow range (e.g., caffeine levels are mostly around 0.3, with only a few data points having concentrations like 0.2 or 0.4). Given this distribution of the concentration values, is PLS a suitable method for this task?
